# Panel DoubleBuffered property stopped the drawing, is invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, gdi, panel

I have a component, an inherited Panel, where I am overriding the OnPaint event to draw a graph with 500 points. Since I need to do some selection on the graph, it is flickering. I have found this DoubleBuffered property but when I set it to True, in the panel constructor, the drawing disappears. I debug it and I see that the drawing methods still execute but there is nothing on the panel.
Does anyone know why would this happen?

This is .NET 3.5 - C#. Winforms application

```
        try
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            //Draw _graphArea:
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, _graphArea);

            _drawingObjectList.DrawGraph(g, _mainLinePen, _diffLinePen, _dotPen, _dotBrush, _notSelectedBrush, _selectedBrush);

            DrawSelectionRectangle(g);

            g.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Panel descendant constructor:

```
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.UpdateStyles();
```

Comment: I assume this is .Net? language?

Comment: @rene Yes, it is. Sorry. C#. It's in the question now.

Comment: Can you show us your drawing code?

Comment: Is changing the DoubleBuffered property to true the _only_ thing that changed?

Comment: Yes, the code would be helpful. It sounds like the default background is overwriting your image. You might not have set UserPaint, and AllPaintingInWMPaint class bits.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer, @Rich Melton, I can't really post the code cause I have a generic list of graph segments that have a drawing method so the actual g.DrawLine is in them. But I'll try to enter the UserPaint and AllPainting... properties and let you know.

Comment: @bentsai Yes. The only thing. Now I have added the UserPaint and AllPaintingInWMPaint and set them to true but still the same thing.

Comment: Since I can't see your code, this is a guess. You are using e.Graphics that is passed to your method and not creating your own, right? That was [the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113190/double-buffering-when-not-drawing-in-onpaint-why-doesnt-it-work) that plagued another user.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer, @Rich Melton I have tried with UserPaint and AllPaintingInWMPaint and set them to true but still the same thing. Could this be something related to the fact that I have the drawing in the generic elements list?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Yes, this is exactly what I am doing. I have:
    Graphics g = e.Graphics; 
and then I pass it to my objects DrawGraph method. In this method I am going through foreach loop where again I am passing the g to every element draw method.
Should I perhaps use ref with the g parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffered` instead. It's faster and usually works better. Make sure `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint` and `ControlStyles.UserPaint` are also enabled.

Now, `OnPaint()` should be the only stuff that draw to the window and this method must only be called from invalidation or by using `Refresh()`; you must never call `OnPaint()` yourself. Do not dispose the `Graphics` object. If you fail any of those conditions, flickering and various other drawing bugs might occur.

```
class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    protected override void  OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Red);
    }

    void RandomEventThatRequiresRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing all that. I use this.Invalidate() to refresh the graph. But, as you see in my code, I don't do the drawing in the OnPaint. I have other objects that do the drawing.

Comment: @elector It's ok to draw from another method, as long as that method is called by `OnPaint` or a callee and that you are always using the `e.Graphics` object given to you by the event handler. See if removing the g.Dispose call helps. I didn't notice it the first time I saw the question.

Comment: YES! Removing the g.Dispose solved it! I don't know why that was there, I was following examples from C# Graphics book and this peace of code comes from there! Thank you