# Simulate Windows Dragging Effect in a Winform FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag

I'm currently simulating the windows multiple selection rectangle when the user is dragging the mouse. To synchronize our understanding, this picture shows the effect I want to simulate:

[image]

Now I want to simulate this effect on a **FlowLayoutPanel** with some controls inside.

So far I am managed to get the effect almost done:

[image]

What I did here was **putting a unfocused border-less semi-transparent (half the opacity) form on top the main form**. To get the border simulated, I handled `SizeChanged` and `Paint` to draw the border.

However, this solution sometimes flickers, as in the owner border couldn't get cleared on-time:

[image]

I have tried using double buffering on the cover form by setting `DoubleBuffer` to `true`, and override `CreateParam` to set `WM_EX_COMPOSITED`, but neither works.

My question is: How to reduce this artifact?

Thanks a lot!

My code:

For the cover form:

```
public partial class CoverForm : Form
{
    public CoverForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        SizeChanged += (s, e) => Invalidate();
        Paint += (s, e) =>
                     {
                         e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

                         using (var pen = new Pen(Color.DodgerBlue))
                         {
                             e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 1, 1, Size.Width - 2, Size.Height - 2);
                         }
                     };
    }

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

For the main form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // mainPanel is the panel that simulates the dragging effect
    mainPanel.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
                                {
                                    _isMouseDown = true;
                                    _startPosition = e.Location;
                                    coverForm.Location = mainPanel.PointToScreen(e.Location);
                                    coverForm.Show();
                                };
    mainPanel.MouseUp += (s, e) =>
                                {
                                    _isMouseDown = false;
                                    coverForm.Hide();
                                };
    mainPanel.MouseMove += CoverPanelMouseMoveHandler;

    DoubleBuffered = true;
}

~Form1()
{
    if (coverForm != null && !coverForm.IsDisposed)
    {
        coverForm.Dispose();
    }
}

# region Dragging Effect
private void CoverPanelMouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isMouseDown)
    {
        _curPosition = e.Location;
        // find the dragging rectangle
        var rect = CreateRect(_curPosition, _startPosition);

        coverForm.Size = rect.Size;
        coverForm.Location = mainPanel.PointToScreen(rect.Location);

        foreach (Control control in mainPanel.Controls)
        {
            // logic to get button backcolor changed
        }

        mainPanel.Invalidate(true);
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have tried to override `OnPaint` and put my drawing there, but it gave even worse result: the old paints wouldn't get erased:

[image]

Code I modified for cover form:

```
public partial class CoverForm : Form
{
    public CoverForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255)))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, Size.Width - 1, Size.Height - 1);
        }
    }

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Actually the problem I am facing is about **drawing above a FlowLayoutPanel**, not a normal **Panel**. The reason I put `Panel` before was I was seeking answer for my flickering 2-layers design. But since someone approach the problem by **adding control to the panel to get it drawn above all controls**, I would like to point this out: adding control to a panel would be trivial, but `FlowLayoutPanel` will auto-align the newly added control to the next available position, which may screw up the expected effect.

Comment: You could try to use double buffering. www.google.ch/search?q=winforms+double+buffer

Comment: I have tried double buffer but didn't work, and to be honest even worse.

Comment: Maybe You could put those controls inside another control (for example inside a custom control derived from `Panel` control) instead of inside a `Form` directly. Take a look at this thread for some solution suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369163/c-sharp-paint-program-flickering/8369251#8369251.

Comment: Use Refresh() instead.

Comment: @Aybe it still flickers.

Comment: @LukaszM that's what I did. Those buttons are put inside a panel which derives from `Panel` and set `DoubleBuffered` to true. What's more, I don't think the flicker relates the the main form, because the rectangle is another form above the main form, they are quite independent.

Comment: It looks to me as if `DrawRectangle` would do its job but not `Clear(BackColor)`. Try replacing the `Clear` with `FillRectangle`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes tried but didn't work :(

Comment: The simple way to draw selection rectangle is using ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame Method. This doesn't require additional forms. Usually this method is called directly from MouseMove handler. Applying the method twice with the same parameter restores the original underlying image, so MouseMove usually calls DrawReversibleFrame first to remove previous rectangle, then to draw a new one. This is classic Win32/Winforms way to draw selection rectangle. This solution, however, doesn't include internal rectangle color.

Comment: @AlexFarber thanks to point out `ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame`, this seems to be a good solution but it doesn't work for me: it flickers even worse :( Could you please provide a code snippet that may work correctly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at the link I suggested (especially the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8369280/232530). It's showing how to subclass a `Panel` with more things modified than just setting `DoubleBuffered` property ;). The rectangle may be in another form, but if it covers the panel, it also needs to be redrawn.

Comment: @LukaszM all my panels and forms are well double buffered as stated in my question, which is the same as the thread you gave :P

Comment: Have You also tried using `SetStyle` method to set `ControlStyles` (`AllPaintingInWmPaint`, `DoubleBuffered`, `Opaque` and `OptimizedDoubleBuffered`) in the derived class? I cannot see it in the code You posted, but it's definitely in the answer I posted link to ;).

Comment: I set some of them but not all, let me try later and get back to you :) Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Look at group selection here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8494/DrawTools Note that you may invalidate the whole window only when object selection changes, otherwise just clear/draw selection rectangle.

Comment: @LukaszM I tried but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

---

[Video Demo of the Solution: Remember to Switch to 1080p](http://youtu.be/U1Ynd62ZNNI)
Recorded in a VM on a crappy machine.  So kinda slow.

---

You are getting those artifacts because you're doing a combination of 3 things all at once.

The two big ones are moving the form to another location and resizing the form.  It also doesn't help if the form is semi transparent :)  To get a better understanding of what I mean, just open VS2013 up and resize the window very quickly (at the top-left corner, and run in random directions really fast), you will see that around the edges it can't keep up.  And yes, you will get different results when you're resizing from a different position around the window (just think about it for a minute and you will figure it out).

Aybe, provided a pretty clever solution but it doesn't allow you to see through it or see if any updates to the panel....since it basically just copies the last output to a bitmap and uses that as a back buffer (much like what you assume someone might do when doing the selection thing in a paint program).

If you really want to do it with an overlay form and keep it semi-transparent then you will need to eliminate those three things if you don't want artifacts.

---

The code requires quite a bit of WIN32 knowledge....  lucky for you Microsoft has already done the hard part.  We are going to enable per pixel transparency in your cover frame by using the PerPixelAlphaForm by Microsoft (you can google it) I will paste the code here.  It basically just creates a Window with a Style of `WS_EX_LAYERED`.  Keeps a Backbuffer which is AlphaBlended with the screen (simple huh?).

```
/******************************** Module Header ********************************\
Module Name:  PerPixelAlphaForm.cs
Project:      CSWinFormLayeredWindow
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.



This source is subject to the Microsoft Public License.
See http://www.microsoft.com/opensource/licenses.mspx#Ms-PL.
All other rights reserved.

THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, 
EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES 
OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
\*******************************************************************************/

#region Using directives
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#endregion

namespace CSWinFormLayeredWindow
{
    public partial class PerPixelAlphaForm : Form
    {
        public PerPixelAlphaForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                // Add the layered extended style (WS_EX_LAYERED) to this window.
                CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
                createParams.ExStyle |= WS_EX_LAYERED;
                return createParams;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Let Windows drag this window for us (thinks its hitting the title 
        /// bar of the window)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            {
                // Tell Windows that the user is on the title bar (caption)
                message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
            }
            else
            {
                base.WndProc(ref message);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bitmap"></param>
        public void SelectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            SelectBitmap(bitmap, 255);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bitmap">
        /// 
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="opacity">
        /// Specifies an alpha transparency value to be used on the entire source 
        /// bitmap. The SourceConstantAlpha value is combined with any per-pixel 
        /// alpha values in the source bitmap. The value ranges from 0 to 255. If 
        /// you set SourceConstantAlpha to 0, it is assumed that your image is 
        /// transparent. When you only want to use per-pixel alpha values, set 
        /// the SourceConstantAlpha value to 255 (opaque).
        /// </param>
        public void SelectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int opacity)
        {
            // Does this bitmap contain an alpha channel?
            if (bitmap.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("The bitmap must be 32bpp with alpha-channel.");
            }

            // Get device contexts
            IntPtr screenDc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr memDc = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDc);
            IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr hOldBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                // Get handle to the new bitmap and select it into the current 
                // device context.
                hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));
                hOldBitmap = SelectObject(memDc, hBitmap);

                // Set parameters for layered window update.
                Size newSize = new Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                Point sourceLocation = new Point(0, 0);
                Point newLocation = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);
                BLENDFUNCTION blend = new BLENDFUNCTION();
                blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
                blend.BlendFlags = 0;
                blend.SourceConstantAlpha = (byte)opacity;
                blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

                // Update the window.
                UpdateLayeredWindow(
                    this.Handle,     // Handle to the layered window
                    screenDc,        // Handle to the screen DC
                    ref newLocation, // New screen position of the layered window
                    ref newSize,     // New size of the layered window
                    memDc,           // Handle to the layered window surface DC
                    ref sourceLocation, // Location of the layer in the DC
                    0,               // Color key of the layered window
                    ref blend,       // Transparency of the layered window
                    ULW_ALPHA        // Use blend as the blend function
                    );
            }
            finally
            {
                // Release device context.
                ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDc);
                if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SelectObject(memDc, hOldBitmap);
                    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                }
                DeleteDC(memDc);
            }
        }


        #region Native Methods and Structures

        const Int32 WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
        const Int32 HTCAPTION = 0x02;
        const Int32 WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        const Int32 ULW_ALPHA = 0x02;
        const byte AC_SRC_OVER = 0x00;
        const byte AC_SRC_ALPHA = 0x01;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct Point
        {
            public Int32 x;
            public Int32 y;

            public Point(Int32 x, Int32 y)
            { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct Size
        {
            public Int32 cx;
            public Int32 cy;

            public Size(Int32 cx, Int32 cy)
            { this.cx = cx; this.cy = cy; }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        struct ARGB
        {
            public byte Blue;
            public byte Green;
            public byte Red;
            public byte Alpha;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        struct BLENDFUNCTION
        {
            public byte BlendOp;
            public byte BlendFlags;
            public byte SourceConstantAlpha;
            public byte AlphaFormat;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool UpdateLayeredWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcDst,
            ref Point pptDst, ref Size psize, IntPtr hdcSrc, ref Point pprSrc,
            Int32 crKey, ref BLENDFUNCTION pblend, Int32 dwFlags);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hdc);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

OK, that should eliminate your semi-transparent problem.  Remember to get rid of the override of the WndProc (you won't need it).  Set Double-Buffer to `false` and TopMost to `true`.

Now to eliminate the other two problems.  I hope you thought of a way of doing it....but I will give you my solution.  **Always keep the PerPixelAlphaForm the size of your MainForm.  Same location, Same SIZE.**  :)  **And resize the PerPixelAlphaForm's backbuffer bitmap to the same size as well**.  When you do it this way, all you have to do is redraw the Selection Rectangle.  Why? because it overlays the entire MainForm perfectly.

So basically

```
`OnMouseDown`  = Save initial point of mouse, show the Cover layer
`OnMouseMove`  = clear the PerPixelAlphaForm bitmap, draw your rectangle
                 call SelectBitmap again update the form
`OnMouseUp`    = hide the Cover layer (or whatever you want to do)
```

I personally have all this hook up to the Control-Key

---

To clear the PerPixelAlphaForm we need to do in a certain way.  Give all values an Alpha of 0.

```
public void ClearBackbuffer()
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_reference_to_your_backbuffer_);
    g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
    g.FillRectangle(sb, this.ClientRectangle);
    sb.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
}
```

---

[Video Demo of the Solution: Remember to Switch to 1080p](http://youtu.be/U1Ynd62ZNNI)

---

If you need more help, let me know I can find some time to rip the code out of the larger program.  But it seems to me you're the kind of person that likes tinkering with stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : using an additional PictureBox and Bitmap makes the whole thing working

The following Panel draws a rectangle without flickering:

```
internal sealed class MyPanel : Panel
{
    private readonly PictureBox _pictureBox;
    private Bitmap _bitmapContent;
    private Bitmap _bitmapForeground;
    private Point? _point1;
    private Point? _point2;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        _pictureBox = new PictureBox();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_bitmapForeground != null) _bitmapForeground.Dispose();
        _bitmapForeground = new Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height);
        if (_bitmapContent != null) _bitmapContent.Dispose();
        _bitmapContent = new Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height);
        _pictureBox.Size = Size;
        _pictureBox.Image = _bitmapForeground;
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _point1 = e.Location;
        DrawToBitmap(_bitmapContent, new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height));
        SetControlsVisibility(false);
        Controls.Add(_pictureBox);
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    private void SetControlsVisibility(bool visible)
    {
        IEnumerable<Control> ofType = Controls.OfType<Control>();
        foreach (Control control in ofType)
        {
            control.Visible = visible;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.Remove(_pictureBox);
        SetControlsVisibility(true);
        _point1 = null;
        _point2 = null;
        Refresh();
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_point1 != null)
        {
            _point2 = e.Location;
            if (_point1 != null && _point2 != null)
            {
                Point p1 = _point1.Value;
                Point p2 = _point2.Value;
                int x1 = p1.X;
                int y1 = p1.Y;
                int x2 = p2.X;
                int y2 = p2.Y;
                int xmin = Math.Min(x1, x2);
                int ymin = Math.Min(y1, y2);
                int xmax = Math.Max(x1, x2);
                int ymax = Math.Max(y1, y2);
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmapForeground))
                {
                    graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(_bitmapContent, 0, 0, _bitmapContent.Width, _bitmapContent.Height);
                    graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin));
                }
                _pictureBox.Refresh();
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
}
```

However, the rectangle will be below the controls, not sure why ...

Comment: I tried this approach already and got the rectangle below the controls, which was not what I want so I abandoned the approach. This is because the `Panel` is 1 layer lower than those controls in the panel. So drawing on the `Panel` will not cover controls in the panel.

Comment: See my edit, now it draws over and does not flicker :D

Comment: oh I considered this approach also, but didn't really fit my case since it has a disadvantage: if the panel is a `FlowLayoutPanel`, the picture box could not be placed to the desired position. Unfortunately, what I am facing is a `FlowLayoutPanel`. I didn't put this in my question is because I am expecting a 2-layer design, like what I did. Really sorry, but still good answer :)