# Flickering on winform UI

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, panel, flicker

I've implemented a winform UI for Microsoft Robotics Studio to display some sensor data. Currently it draws on a panel every 100 milliseconds using the function below. The issue is I'm seeing flickering on the panel I'm drawing and when dragging the window it feels very sluggish. Based what other people have encountered on this forum I used *DoubleBuffered = true* when creating the form to no avail.
Any tips on how I can improve this ? Thanks in advance.

This function draws lines on the panel representing a radar,

```
    private void DrawRadarLines()
    {
        myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        formGraphics = radarMap.CreateGraphics();

        for (int i = 0; i < sensorNetworkNum * 5; i++)
        {
            formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 
                (float)(195 - radarMapLines[i, 0] * scalingFactor), 
                (float)(195 - radarMapLines[i, 1] * scalingFactor), 
                (float)(195 - radarMapLines[i, 2] * scalingFactor), 
                (float)(195 - radarMapLines[i, 3] * scalingFactor));
        }

        myPen.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty inevitable when you use CreateGraphics(), you are drawing straight to the screen.  Just don't, call radarMap.Invalidate() instead and move the code to a Paint event handler for radarMap.  Now double-buffering *[the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113190/double-buffering-when-not-drawing-in-onpaint-why-doesnt-it-work/3113515#3113515)* will work.

Comment: Is it still necessary to call Dispose at the end ? From my understanding Dispose clears the resources.