# Drawing on the bottom of a BufferedGraphics

Tags: c#, graphics

I have a `BufferedGraphics` instance and I draw some graphs on it. I'd like to create a function called `DrawLegends` that takes an instance of `BufferedGraphics` and draws two strings as legend.

I can create a `PointF` instance that points to (0, 0), but I want to put the legend on the bottom. How should I proceed with that? Can I do it with the `BufferedGraphics` instance or would I also need the panel that I'm drawing on?

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: Using BufferedGraphics is always wrong.  Use this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3113515/17034

Comment: @musefan If you write your comment as an answer, I'll take it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing is that you need to know the dimensions (mainly height) of the drawing canvas (i.e. the panel). This will be used to ultimately calculate the position of the legend. So if you don't have the height information stored elsewhere then yes, you will have to use the panel to some degree

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day pretty much all objects which are drawn to the screen can be manually drawn on, as under the covers they have or expose a graphics object to paint onto when you feel like it.

So if you do your drawing on a graphics object or whatever you are currently using, then when you are done drawing just paint that graphics object onto whatever control you want to display it in. As you can treat graphics objects a bit like images. There is no reason why you cannot pass in the underlying controls graphics object you want to paint onto rather than making your own graphics object, but if you have a method which does:

```
void DrawGraph(string xLegend, string yLegend, IList<XYValues> values, Graphics graphics);
```

Then you can draw onto that graphics object with the data, call invalidate and your done.